# Map New array of object from array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have one array of object. I want to map new array.

I want to create this array into another array of object like this

```
let arr = [{
    "rn": "1",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Bangladesh ",
    "EnergySourceId": "1",
    "SourceName": "Nuclear",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "2",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Bangladesh ",
    "EnergySourceId": "2",
    "SourceName": "Fossil fuels",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "176",
    "Y_2012": "144",
    "Y_2013": "218",
    "Y_2014": "159",
    "Y_2015": "149",
    "Y_2016": "154.7000",
    "CAGR": "-2.55"
  },
  {
    "rn": "8",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Bangladesh ",
    "EnergySourceId": "8",
    "SourceName": "Biomass and waste",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "9",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Bangladesh ",
    "EnergySourceId": "9",
    "SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  }, {
    "rn": "10",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Bangladesh ",
    "EnergySourceId": "11",
    "SourceName": "Generation",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "771",
    "Y_2012": "882",
    "Y_2013": "1103",
    "Y_2014": "1159",
    "Y_2015": "1183",
    "Y_2016": "1214.7000",
    "CAGR": "9.52"
  },
  {
    "rn": "11",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "5",
    "CountryName": "Czech Republic ",
    "EnergySourceId": "1",
    "SourceName": "Nuclear",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "12",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "5",
    "CountryName": "Czech Republic ",
    "EnergySourceId": "2",
    "SourceName": "Fossil fuels",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "1545",
    "Y_2012": "2286",
    "Y_2013": "3242",
    "Y_2014": "4172",
    "Y_2015": "4212",
    "Y_2016": "4273.2400",
    "CAGR": "22.56"
  },
  {
    "rn": "13",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "5",
    "CountryName": "Czech Republic ",
    "EnergySourceId": "3",
    "SourceName": "Hydroelectricity",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "3967",
    "Y_2012": "3734",
    "Y_2013": "4719",
    "Y_2014": "4991",
    "Y_2015": "5037",
    "Y_2016": "5757.0000",
    "CAGR": "7.73"
  },
  {
    "rn": "22",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "2",
    "SourceName": "Fossil fuels",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "769",
    "Y_2012": "731",
    "Y_2013": "742",
    "Y_2014": "732",
    "Y_2015": "746",
    "Y_2016": "760.0000",
    "CAGR": "-0.24"
  },
  {
    "rn": "23",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "3",
    "SourceName": "Hydroelectricity",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "24",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "4",
    "SourceName": "Geothermal",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "25",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "5",
    "SourceName": "Tide and wave",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "26",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "6",
    "SourceName": "Solar",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "1",
    "Y_2013": "2",
    "Y_2014": "6",
    "Y_2015": "10",
    "Y_2016": "10.7120",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "27",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "7",
    "SourceName": "Wind",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "113",
    "Y_2012": "135",
    "Y_2013": "151",
    "Y_2014": "153",
    "Y_2015": "165",
    "Y_2016": "134.0000",
    "CAGR": "3.47"
  },
  {
    "rn": "28",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "8",
    "SourceName": "Biomass and waste",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "4.8000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "29",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "9",
    "SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "30",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "8",
    "CountryName": "Honduras ",
    "EnergySourceId": "11",
    "SourceName": "Generation",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "882",
    "Y_2012": "867",
    "Y_2013": "895",
    "Y_2014": "891",
    "Y_2015": "921",
    "Y_2016": "909.5120",
    "CAGR": "0.62"
  },
  {
    "rn": "35",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "5",
    "SourceName": "Tide and wave",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "36",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "6",
    "SourceName": "Solar",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "8",
    "Y_2015": "8",
    "Y_2016": "8.2500",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "37",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "7",
    "SourceName": "Wind",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "38",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "8",
    "SourceName": "Biomass and waste",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "39",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "9",
    "SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "0",
    "Y_2012": "0",
    "Y_2013": "0",
    "Y_2014": "0",
    "Y_2015": "0",
    "Y_2016": "0.0000",
    "CAGR": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "rn": "40",
    "EnergyParameterId": "4",
    "CountryId": "13",
    "CountryName": "Sri Lanka ",
    "EnergySourceId": "11",
    "SourceName": "Generation",
    "UnitId": "",
    "Y_2011": "22877",
    "Y_2012": "23289",
    "Y_2013": "24361",
    "Y_2014": "25626",
    "Y_2015": "26783",
    "Y_2016": "26807.6500",
    "CAGR": "3.22"
  }
];
console.log(arr);
```

I want to convert this into

```
let newArr = [{
 'CountryName': srilanka,
 'SourceName': Nuclear,
  'data': [0,0,0,0,0,0]
}];
```

I have tried to loop and map but it did not worked for me...

```
let createArrLineChart = [];
debugger;    
for (let index = 0; index < newArr ; index++) {
  // const element = newArr [index];
  // let createObj:any = {};
  // createObj.Name = element.CountryName;
  // createArrLineChart.push(createObj)
  var result:any = newArr.map((person: any) => {
    person.startsWith("Y_");
  });
  console.log(result)
  console.log(newArr[index]);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does your code have `ArrGetEnergyStatisticsData` when you present the input data as `arr`? Can you make the question consistent?

Comment: accually i have added my angular code in this Sorry for that

Comment: @trincot how can i do this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the issues in your attempt:

- The loop condition `index < newArr` should actually be `index < newArr.length`
- As `person` is a plain object and not a string, calling `startsWith` on it will not work. You need to iterate the object's keys.
- `newArr` seems the wrong reference, as that would be the *result* from `arr`.

You could get the two names via destructuring, and the year-keys via a filter.

For example:

```js
const arr = [{"rn": "1","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "1","CountryName": "Bangladesh ","EnergySourceId": "1","SourceName": "Nuclear","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "2","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "1","CountryName": "Bangladesh ","EnergySourceId": "2","SourceName": "Fossil fuels","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "176","Y_2012": "144","Y_2013": "218","Y_2014": "159","Y_2015": "149","Y_2016": "154.7000","CAGR": "-2.55"},{"rn": "8","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "1","CountryName": "Bangladesh ","EnergySourceId": "8","SourceName": "Biomass and waste","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "9","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "1","CountryName": "Bangladesh ","EnergySourceId": "9","SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"}, {"rn": "10","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "1","CountryName": "Bangladesh ","EnergySourceId": "11","SourceName": "Generation","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "771","Y_2012": "882","Y_2013": "1103","Y_2014": "1159","Y_2015": "1183","Y_2016": "1214.7000","CAGR": "9.52"},{"rn": "11","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "5","CountryName": "Czech Republic ","EnergySourceId": "1","SourceName": "Nuclear","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "12","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "5","CountryName": "Czech Republic ","EnergySourceId": "2","SourceName": "Fossil fuels","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "1545","Y_2012": "2286","Y_2013": "3242","Y_2014": "4172","Y_2015": "4212","Y_2016": "4273.2400","CAGR": "22.56"},{"rn": "13","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "5","CountryName": "Czech Republic ","EnergySourceId": "3","SourceName": "Hydroelectricity","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "3967","Y_2012": "3734","Y_2013": "4719","Y_2014": "4991","Y_2015": "5037","Y_2016": "5757.0000","CAGR": "7.73"},{"rn": "22","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "2","SourceName": "Fossil fuels","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "769","Y_2012": "731","Y_2013": "742","Y_2014": "732","Y_2015": "746","Y_2016": "760.0000","CAGR": "-0.24"},{"rn": "23","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "3","SourceName": "Hydroelectricity","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "24","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "4","SourceName": "Geothermal","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "25","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "5","SourceName": "Tide and wave","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},
{"rn": "26","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "6","SourceName": "Solar","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "1","Y_2013": "2","Y_2014": "6","Y_2015": "10","Y_2016": "10.7120","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "27","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "7","SourceName": "Wind","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "113","Y_2012": "135","Y_2013": "151","Y_2014": "153","Y_2015": "165","Y_2016": "134.0000","CAGR": "3.47"},{"rn": "28","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "8","SourceName": "Biomass and waste","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "4.8000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "29","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "9","SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "30","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "8","CountryName": "Honduras ","EnergySourceId": "11","SourceName": "Generation","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "882","Y_2012": "867","Y_2013": "895","Y_2014": "891","Y_2015": "921","Y_2016": "909.5120","CAGR": "0.62"},{"rn": "35","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "5","SourceName": "Tide and wave","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "36","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "6","SourceName": "Solar","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "8","Y_2015": "8","Y_2016": "8.2500","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "37","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "7","SourceName": "Wind","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "38","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "8","SourceName": "Biomass and waste","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "39","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "9","SourceName": "Hydroelectric pumped storage","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "0","Y_2012": "0","Y_2013": "0","Y_2014": "0","Y_2015": "0","Y_2016": "0.0000","CAGR": "0.00"},{"rn": "40","EnergyParameterId": "4","CountryId": "13","CountryName": "Sri Lanka ","EnergySourceId": "11","SourceName": "Generation","UnitId": "","Y_2011": "22877","Y_2012": "23289","Y_2013": "24361","Y_2014": "25626","Y_2015": "26783","Y_2016": "26807.6500","CAGR": "3.22"}];

const newArr = arr.map(({CountryName, SourceName, ...rest}) => ({
    CountryName,
    SourceName,
    data: Object.keys(rest).filter(key => key.startsWith("Y_")).map(key => +rest[key])
}));

console.log(newArr);
```